# Defining regular expression as a javascript variable results in error

Tags: javascript, regex

Concider the following regex all letters + some ascii hex characters (ï, ë, ..) :

```
   var regexOnlyLetters = /[a-zA-Z]|[\xCO-\xFF]/;
```

\xCO gives me the following error: illegal hexadecimal escape sequence.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an `O`, uppercase letter O instead of zero `0` in `\xCO`.